# Reference error while trying to encapsulate an animation function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to put a function into its own class object. Here it is below.

The canvas property holds the DOM functions, and I am getting an error for the next property, ctx, which should refer to a method defined in canvas.

So property ctx should refer to the ctx method defined in the canvas property. Bt when the page loads, the dev tools are telling me that there is a reference error at that point - that canvas is not defined.

I also encounter this problem when the Canvas is defined in an external global variable.

```js
var DrawCrash = {

  canvas : function () {  
    DOM methods here
  },
  ctx : canvas.ctx,
  pointer : canvas.pointer,
  particles : "",
  nbrParticles : 160,
  speed : 6,
  strength : .4,
  radius : 4,
  perspective : 0.5,
  ang : null,
  CosOrSin1 : null,
  CosOrSin2 : null,
  //functions
  setSpeed : function (_inputSpeed) {
    this.speed = _inputSpeed;
  },

  startDrawing : function () {

    pointer.down = function()
    {

      } 
    }
    run();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is too much code. Please reduce it to 20-30 lines.

Comment: @torazaburo ok there we g0

Comment: `ctx : canvas.ctx` is where the problem is. `canvas` must not be available in the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

I believe canvas is not available. Don't put the line `ctx: canvas.ctx`. Instead define it in a separate statement after this.

```
DrawCrash.ctx = DrawCrash.canvas.ctx
```

You are trying to reference it before it is created

Comment: So, are you recommending something like setting ctx to null, then running that line DrawCrash.ctx = DrawCrash.canvas.ctx after the object is constructed?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to set it to null also

Comment: it just makes it right then and there from DrawCrash.ctx = thing? neat.